# Get windows logon user in asp.net web forms iis

Tags: asp.net

I want to get the active directory login user in asp.net web forms.I used the below code snippet,but it won't work on either runtime or iis.

```
Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"].ToString();
```

Comment: What is the error message you are getting? If you are getting an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;` to get details of the authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

Use Directory Entry to get the user status.

```
string username = "";
string userpassword = "";
bool valid = false;
using (DirectoryEntry Direntry = new DirectoryEntry(path, username, userpassword))   
  {
      using (DirectorySearcher Dsearch = new DirectorySearcher(Direntry))
            {
                Dsearch.Filter = "(cn=" + username + ")";
                try
                {
                    SearchResult adsSearchResult = Dsearch.FindOne();
                    if (adsSearchResult != null)
                    {
                        valid = true;
                    }   
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
                finally
                {
                    Direntry.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One additional change you may need to make is in the web.config file.

Change the authentication mode from Forms to Windows.

> ```
> <authentication mode="Windows"/>
> ```

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.authenticationsection?view=netframework-4.8)